# Bitwise operator <<

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm learning about the left shift operator but I'm struggling understanding this piece of text that say :

> If E1 is negative and bite shifting(E2) has a 0 as significant bit the result will be a positive number
> If E1 is positive and bite shifting(E2) has a 1 as significant bit the result will be a negative number

AFAIK i translate a

> 0 as a significant bit as a number

as a 0 at the left, so i tried with this

```
int E1 = -56;
int E2 = 2;

int res = E1 << E2;
System.out.println(res);
```

But it print `-224`

I know that the result is right because -56 is 11111111111111111111111111001000 and shifting by 2 position return 11111111111111111111111100100000

Comment: Where did you get this quote from? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: It's from an italian Java book, I don't know how to traduce with 100% accuracy the word, with google translate i get this 
"Furthermore, if E1 is negative and the shifting of the bits places a bit with the value 0 on the most significant bit, the result will be a positive number; if, on the other hand, E1 is positive and shifting the bits places a bit with value 1 on the most significant bit, the result will be a negative number"

Comment: It just means the sign of the result will depend on the bit that after the shift ends up as the most significant bit. 0 -> positive, 1 -> negative.

Comment: Omg thank you, I was driving mad!

Comment: What do you mean with "undefined behaviour"?

Comment: oh yea sorry my bad, i was browsing c++ tag and somehow ended up in java x)

Comment: @Henry post as answer?

Comment: @greybeard The question is about what the text you edited means. You have no business changing it whatsoever. Edit rejected.

Comment: When you say "significant bit", you really mean "sign bit"

Comment: @user207421: I created a [room for views on editing other's posts in general and my edit of this question in particular](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1750/editing-others-posts)